# OSX - Delete Folder From /Library/Application Support/TestAPI

Tags: java, macos

I am using Java to delete TestAPI folder from OSX using below code
but not able to delete

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /Library/Application\\ Support/Test\\ API");
```

AND

```
File f_objFile = new File("/Library/Application Support/Test\\ API");
deleteDir(f_objFile);
_____________________________________________________________________

 static void deleteDir(File file) {
    File[] contents = file.listFiles();
    if (contents != null) {
        for (File f: contents) {
            if (! Files.isSymbolicLink(f.toPath())) {
                deleteDir(f);
            }
        }
    }
    file.delete();
}
```

This folder has full permissions to delete 
Please help me out from this.
Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

First can you make a main method and just test your path with something like:

```
if (Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("Your Directory Path"))) {
    System.out.println("The directory exist");
}
```

Now you know that the directory path is the one that you need. Please try your delete method and if you have some exceptions please add them as information so we can help further.

Comment: Please note that "/Library/Application Support/...." is system path 
If we call delete as below 
    
    if (Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("Your Directory Path"))) {
        System.out.println("The directory exist");
        Files.delete("Your Directory Path")
    }
This will get the error like.. ' java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException '